# Monotonicity of quadratic forms in positive semidefinite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

I'm interested in some kind of monotonicity quality of quadratic forms. Let $A$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite (n x n)-matrix. Suppose we have two real n-dimensional vectors a and b, for which holds $0 \leq a \leq b$, where "$\leq$" is applied componentwise. Does
\begin{align}
a'Aa \leq b'Ab
\end{align}
now also hold? For diagonal matrix this holds, since it can only have positive entries, due to the positive semidefiniteness.
My general proof idea is that $Da=b$ for $D=diag(b_1/a_1,\dots, b_n/a_n)$ which leads to $b'Ab - a'Aa = a'(DAD-A)a$. Now if $DAD-A$ was positive semidefinite, this would conclude the proof. This where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take $$ A = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & -5 \\ 
-5 & 26 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

with
$$ a = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ b = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
15  \\ 
3  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Hello. I couldn't email because Google along with gmail are blocked in China, so I can only leave a message here. May I have the article by Hurwitz about the Diophantine equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^2=k\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$ having no positive integer solutions for $k>n$? My email is siddsc@foxmail.com . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @youthdoo  I put it at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf